# Prime, non-maximal, non-principal Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was wondering if $(x,y) \unlhd \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ is a prime ideal that is neither maximal nor principal because I believe that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y] / (x,y) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ which is an integral domain, but not a field. Is this reasoning correct? Thanks

Comment: Almost. You should justify it is not principal, though, even if it is very plausible.

Comment: What sort of argument should I use to show that the ideal is not principal? I am not sure how to show this.

Comment: You suppose there's a generator $f(x,y)$, and you have to use the degree (total, or in $x$ or in $y$) to show that $x$ and $y$ can't both be multiples of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

$\;\;\;\;\;\;$Yes. Since $\Bbb Z$ is not a field then the kernel $(x,y)$ of the ring epimorphism  $\Psi:\Bbb Z[x,y]\to\Bbb Z$ defined by $\Psi:f(x,y)\mapsto f(0,0)$ is not maximal.

$\;\;\;\;\;\;x,y$ are coprime polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x,y]$. $(x,y)$ is obviously proper, i.e. no units in $(x,y)$, but not principal or else its generators would be common divisors of $x,y$ and thus units.

$\;\;\;\;\;\;$Also, consider the fact that $(x,y)$ is properly contained in the proper $\Bbb Z[x,y]$ ideal $$\mathcal A:=\{f(x,y)\in\Bbb Z[x,y]:2|f(0,0)\}$$ made of those polynomials with even constant term.